# How to save users uploaded data in my html website?

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to receive data when user submitted a form
Something like create a login account in website
and then save the account data in a database

I know how to take out the data from the submitted form, but can't save the data in local file
Without using server, I tried to save the passing data as rewrite an existing local file but seems like js forbids to change a local file.

If it must to be done with a server, please tell me how to set up a local host server and how to direct the data from script to server since I don't have something like ftp server

Is it must to be saved in a database software something like SQL?

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local storage. Just read something about that in w3schools. Make sure to double check your usecase as only non critical data should be stored in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is simple and you don't need to save it permanently, You can use localStorage as @Rajesh said above. But otherwise, you need to use a DB like MySQL or Mongo to save the data and needs frameworks like express to save and retrieve data from the DB (If you needs the things to be done using NodeJS, otherwise you can use any backend technologies).

Answer (score 0):

Save in localStorage.Do the following:

```
localStorage.setItem('username','Tom');
localStorage.setItem('password','123456');
```

After that, your data is saved in local storage. You can check by right click on chrome, select 'inspect',select 'Application', on the left you will find 'Local Storage';

I guess you may want to have access to the saved data. do the following:

```
  let username=localStorage.getItem('username')
  let password=localStorage.getItem('password')
  localStorage.clear()//will clear everything in localStorage
```

You may also want to clear the data.

```
localStorage.removeItem('username')
localStorage.removeItem('password')
localStorage.clear()//will clear everything in localStorage
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date.
2. window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost
       when the browser tab is closed)

Plaese refer the following link

[html5_webstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)